# Is there a way I can change the background color of the whole input bar in Message Kit?

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I wish to change the background color of the input accessory bar to a reddish color. In the example code for MessageKit, there isn't any to change the background color. And running this piece of code doesn't work:

```
messageInputBar.backgroundColor = .red
or
messageInputBar.backgroundView.backgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to color the different parts on the `InputBarAccessoryView`, use these snippets:

1. Coloring the content view:

[image]

```
messageInputBar.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
```

2. Coloring the text input view:

[image]

```
messageInputBar.inputTextView.backgroundColor = .red
```

3. Coloring the full view:

[image]

```
messageInputBar.backgroundView.backgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? :

```
messageInputBar.contentView.backgroundColor
```